# Python best way to call transformative functions

Tags: python

I'm creating a transformative function that takes two lists.

one list has the values that I want to transform and the second list has a list of functions that I want to send the values to in order.

```
def directing_function(value_list, func_list):
    value = None
    transformed = []
    for x in value_list:
        value = func_list[0](x)
        for y in func_list[1:]:
            value = y(value)
        transformed.append(value)
    return transformed
```

Granted this is a mockup as I haven't written it exactly. I'm trying to figure out the best way to reference the possible functions. I considered Enum, a dictionary for case...

Have any of you ran into this type of issue before? What do you feel might be the best way to approach this from an organizational and ease of use standpoint?

If the order of functions needed was static obviously it would be easier, but they will change and repeat and change based on need.

EDIT: The code is more psudo code, I'm more concerned with how to reference the functions as the list of functions itself may be both long and repetitive.

Also fixed the psudo for clarity.

Comment: Note you're only taking the last value of `func_list`, if it exists, which might not be your intent. Also, look into list comprehensions. This could easily be written as such. I think a list is still the best approach, but this function is needlessly verbose when it could be much simpler.

Comment: So you're just trying to apply multiple functions to every element in a list?

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding what the problem is. Is having the functions be a list causing any issues? If you intend on using all the functions for each `x` why use anything other than a list?

Comment: Is the `append` supposed to be in the inner loop? Also, you don't need to declare values in Python. Even if your intent is to have a default, the `value` will be overwritten on any inner iteration, so then if an empty list occurs, it will output the wrong value. This function does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh - this is more psudeo code, I'm trying to figure out the best way to approach this without reinventing the wheel.  The output of function 1 should be the input of function 2 and so on. also append should occur after the functions are done but before the next x is called.

Comment: @BeRT2me see response to alexander, couldn't tag you in that comment as well :(

Comment: @josh-stackoverflow having the funcs in a list isn't a problem, but depending on how verbose the list (of functions) gets based on wants of the user, I was wondering if something like a key or enum might be more appropriae, or another way I'm not thinking of.

Comment: After your edit I'm even more confused as to your goal. With a values list of length `n` and a functions list of length `m` are you expecting an output list of length `n` with each value applied to the chain of `m` functions? I'm really not sure why you'd need anything other than a list. Pushing all computation to init time in Cameron Ridell's answer below would make sense if you are constantly doingcomputationally expensive function calls of a known input but as you've described the problem there is no need to.

Comment: my goal is really concerning the organization of the functions to make it easy from an ease of use perspective.  but given the information here, it doesn't seem like there needs to be more than a list of the function names, even if that list gets very long

Comment: In that case my suggestion would be to just use the list of function names, or in the case of very simple functions (i.e. a single expression) I would leave it anonymous as a lambda: `[func1, func2, ..., lambda x: x * x + 10, ...]`.

Comment: Appreciate it @josh-stackoverflow , I will do that. And thanks for all the other valuable information. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dictionary, and depending on the broader problem at hand I would use either of these approaches:

As far as I see if, there is no real reason to intermediate your function objects with an Enum (or similar). That's just adding 1 more layer of complexity that is not needed in Python.

### Approach 1: Flat dictionary w/ tuple keys

This approach is ideal if you're only ever interested in selecting the result of 1 func/value pair at a time. If you want to select all outputs with the same function (or likewise, all outputs that share a specific value), I may reach for one of the below approaches.

```py
from itertools import product

def directing_function(value_list, func_list):
    transformed = {}
    for func, v in product(func_list, value_list):
        transformed[func, v] = func(v)
    return transformed

def hello(x):
    return x + 1

def world(x):
    return x ** 2

out = directing_function([1, 2, 4, 8], [hello, world])

print(out)
# {
#    (<function hello at 0x7f765c017c10>, 1): 2,
#    (<function hello at 0x7f765c017c10>, 2): 3,
#    ...
#    (<function world at 0x7f765c017160>, 4): 16,
#    (<function world at 0x7f765c017160>, 8): 64
# }

print(out[hello, 2]) # 3
print(out[world, 4]) # 16
```

### Approach 2: Nested dictionary w/ func as outer layer

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def directing_function(value_list, func_list):
    transformed = defaultdict(dict)
    for func in func_list:
        transformed[func] = {v: func(v) for v in value_list} 
    return transformed

def hello(x):
    return x + 1

def world(x):
    return x ** 2

out = directing_function([1, 2, 4, 8], [hello, world])

print(out)
# defaultdict(dict,
#             {<function __main__.hello(x)>: {1: 2, 2: 3, 4: 5, 8: 9},
#              <function __main__.world(x)>: {1: 1, 2: 4, 4: 16, 8: 64}})

print(out[world])    # {1: 1, 2: 4, 4: 16, 8: 64}
print(out[world][4]) # 16
print(out[hello][2]) # 3
```

### Approach 2.1: Nested dictionary w/ value as outer layer

Pretty much the same as above, but swap the layers of the nested dictionary

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def directing_function(value_list, func_list):
    transformed = defaultdict(dict)
    for v in value_list:
        transformed[v] = {func: func(v) for func in func_list} 
    return transformed
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
f1 = lambda x: x+1
f2 = lambda x: x*2
f3 = lambda x: x**3
funcs = [f1, f2, f3]
```

Doing:

```
# Iterate through your functions.
    # Use map to easily apply a function 
    # to every element in a list.

for f in funcs:
    l = map(f, l)

l = list(l)
print(l)
 
# Output:
[64, 216, 512, 1000]
```